# UserDict instance is not getting updated, as per the __init__ method. why?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, python-3.8, init

The last print statement gives `{}` instead of
`{'key1':'value1', 'apple':'fruit', 'tomato':'vegetable'}`.
Why so?

```
class UserDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, dict=None):
        self = {}
        print(self)
        if dict is not None:
            self.update(dict)
            print(self)
        print(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myd = {'key1':'value1', 'apple':'fruit', 'tomato':'vegetable'}
    ud = UserDict(dict=myd)
    print(ud)
```

Comment: The problem is because you assign `self = {}`. What do you expect this to do?

Comment: `self = {}` This recreates `self` as a new _local_ variable inside the function.  Local variables are lost when the function exits.

Comment: instead `self = {}` do something like `self.x = {}` then `x.update(dict)`

Comment: @JohnGordon More precisely, `self` is already declared as a local variable in the parameter list. And that variable is reassigned so it no longer references the `UserDict` instance that is originally passed in.

Comment: I suggest adding `print(self)` before you do `self = {}`. Does this give you any insight into what is going wrong?

Comment: Side note: don't use `dict` as a parameter name since it is already a built-in class name.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, `print(id(self))` gave me the clarity. Thanks for your suggestion. The `id(self)` before `self={}` and the `id(ud)` are the same, while `id(self)` after `self={}` is different.

Comment: `print(self.__class__)` gives more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You override `self` during the `__init__` function, which means you're reassigning a local variable named `self`, which is a completely new `dict` that gets deleted as soon as `__init__` is done.

Try updating `self` directly:

```
class UserDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, dict=None):
        if dict is not None:
            self.update(dict)
```

You still forgot to call `super().__init__` to make sure the underlying dictionary is initialized.

As a side note, it's highly discouraged to override the dict built-in name in variable names. Also, do keep in mind that dict by default accepts an iterable of tuples (key, value), and keyword argument mapping.

Fixed code:

```
class UserDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data=None, /, **kwargs):
        if data:
            super().__init__(data, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Last but not least, `UserDict` is already used by the `collections` builtin library. I spent a few minutes writing an answer before realizing you implemented a new dict and called it `UserDict`. I suggest naming it differently to avoid further confusion with builtins.